# Using webpack externals in a script loaded with a script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm trying to host react components across microservices. I want to bundle my javascript files into a bundle, and make it available for other microservices to download it and use it. As all our microservices use react, and some other dependencies, I don't want to include them in the bundled file. I've added them to my webpack config as externals:

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
   ...
},
```

This works, as these dependencies are not bundled, however the "hosted component" is not working when I want to access it in other microservices (consumer side) like:

```
<script src="path/to/hosted"></script>
```

I've tried to put dependencies on the window object on the consumer side:

```
import React from 'react';

window.libs.React = React;
...
```

but that way I can access React on the hoster side like `window.libs.React`, which seems inconvenient to develop. Right now I think I should solve this somehow within the webpack bundling, but I'm stuck with it. Any suggestions what plugins should I check, or any existing methodologies for this problem?

PS: The concept is not my idea, I just have to implement it, so I can't really change the whole concept to for example using npm packages instead of this whole component sharing thing.